# Dual Monitor without amdgpu-pro driver, to avoid Eclipse lag

Tags: drivers, graphics, eclipse, amd-graphics

english isnt my first language but i hope that what i write is readable and understandable to a point where i might find help
also if i violated someones forum rules or feelings let me know i try to fix it asap

**Data:**
Graphics Card: amd r9 285
installed driver: [amdgpu-pro-17.10-446706](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx)
Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 64-bit
desktop environment: gnome
If you want to know anything else, i hope i respond quick enough to hold your attention.

**The Problem:**

1. Eclipse has a high input lag if you install amdgpu-pro drivers because (to my understanding atleast) the rendering of the editor is switched to software rendering instead of hardware rendering which results in a coursor (only withing the editor, everything else is completely fine) that moves agonizingly slow the bigger your file (more text = higher lag) and/or eclipse window gets and makes coding miserable.
   [An actual submitted bug report (not by me).](https://community.amd.com/thread/214252)
2. If i dont install the aforementioned driver it results in only one monitor of mine working properly, the other one gets detected (if i open the display settings) but is constanly black (but if there was a window open before i rebooted after uninstalling the graphics driver they will still be inside that black monitor and i cant properly acces them until i set the monitor to mirror one another). But atleast Eclipse works properly, yay.

**My Solutions, that arent actually solutions because they dont work**
(yet, because i dont know how to make such magic happen)**:**

4. enable hardware rendering without having a graphics driver installed
5. install a driver that actually works (does not have to support steam or actually gaming)
6. i read that installing another kernel[3] helps, but i hope someone here can help me with understanding why that is even an option and works (i dont want to get onto this thin ice without knowing what i am doing)
7. buy an nvidia graphics card, i'd be pissed if i have to do this

**P.S.:** I probably should mention that everything was fine until i decided to install the amd drivers today to use steam (which crashed before installing the drivers, but works fine while they are installed). I recall having this problem previously but dont know what demon i summoned to get rid of this.

I hope this problem is entertaining enough to be worthwile,

have a nice day

[3] >10 rep link max reached: ttps://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/amd-linux/894795-typing-in-eclipse-very-laggy-ubuntu-16-04-unity-rx480-amdgpu-pro-16-30